# How to string datepicker to timepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am working on an app involving datepicker and timepicker and would like to set the onClick for the datepicker "ok" button to spawn the timepicker dialog box. Is this possible or would it be better to just create 2 separate buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can just listen for the return of the `DatePicker` and use that as the event to launch the `TimePicker`.